# FInd value in array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given the following:

```
var myArray = [
  { 
    id: "3283267",
    innerArray: ["434","6565","343","3665"]
  },
  {
    id: "9747439",
    innerArray: ["3434","38493","4308403840","34343"]
  },
  {
    id: "0849374",
    innerArray: ["343434","57575","389843","38493"]
  }
];
```

How would I search the objects inside *myArray* to determine if the string "38493" is present in the *innerArray* and then return a new array with the id of the object....like such:

```
var arrayWithIds = ["9747439", "0849374"];
```

Comment: Write a loop that uses `currentElement.innerArray.indexOf("38493")` to tell if the string is in the array and pushes `currentElement.id` onto the result array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution using `Array.forEach` and `Array.indexOf` functions:

```
var search =  "38493", 
    result = [];

myArray.forEach(function(o) {
     if (o.innerArray.indexOf(search) !== -1) this.push(o.id);   
}, result);

console.log(result);  // ["9747439", "0849374"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can filter your array and then map ids (using ES6 syntax):

```
const arrayWithIds = myArray
  .filter(a => a.innerArray.includes('38493'))
  .map(a => a.id)
```

Here is ES5 alternative:

```
var arrayWithIds = myArray
  .filter(function(a) {
    return ~a.innerArray.indexOf('38493');
  })
  .map(function(a) {
    return a.id;
  })
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use ES5.

Answer (score 0):

ES5 way, you may also do as follows.

```js
var myArray = [
  { 
    id: "3283267",
    innerArray: ["434","6565","343","3665"]
  },
  {
    id: "9747439",
    innerArray: ["3434","38493","4308403840","34343"]
  },
  {
    id: "0849374",
    innerArray: ["343434","57575","389843","38493"]
  }
],
 searchData = "38493",
     result = myArray.reduce(function(p,c){
                             return ~c.innerArray.indexOf(searchData) ? (p.push(c.id),p) : p;
                             },[]);
console.log(result);
```